# Shinny (R studio) app doesn't work and doesn't appear "Runapp"

Tags: r

I am working with Library shiny. I was doing a project on my computer and it worked. The project can do a boxplot with a CSV and the inputs are a date and an integer.

I sent the project to my friend so that she could try but she couldn't get the "Run app" icon. She ran the code and she got the ui but it doesn't appear the boxplot when she types the date and the integer.

I tried to reload librarys but it didn't work. I also changed the working directory. Does anybody have a suggestion? 
It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure shiny and all of the library dependencies are installed on her machine.
- Make sure Rstudio is updated to the latest version
- Sometimes I have had to just simply put a new line in the file and save it again for the run app button to show. but the line that makes that come up would be 
  `shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)`

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try it 